# I've completed my mobile game - now what?

Tags: unity, android, ios, mobile, publishing

After months of development, I've finally finished my mobile app, but I have no idea what to do next. I want to publish my app to the Google Play Store and the App Store, yet I don't know how. I've done tons of research and every single website shows different methods and requirements. I've seen that I'm supposed to have some kind of license, a specific certificate, and all these other connections that I'm really confused on how I'm supposed to get them, and where to even start. I've gotten as far as getting Apple Developer and Google Developer, but that's basically it. I just want a simple step-to-step guide. I've already looked on StackExchange for an answer, but all have slightly different questions, such as marketing the app and updating the app, but nothing on how to get it out there.

I'm using Unity as an engine and X-Code via my Mac to test my app on my iPhone.

I appreciate any help in advance. Thank you!

Comment: So you've found multiple different methods. Which ones did you try? Where did they not work? The more concrete you can make this, the better we can help address your specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think official site is best guide, this may help:

https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/submissions/

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/